# Suspend/Kill and waiting thread

Tags: c#

I have an thread executing a function and couple of threads blocked using AutoResetEvent. All this is happening in an WCF service

Is it possible the from an client application I can suspend/kill the waiting threads. I keep track of the ManagedThreadIds

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to, even if you could, for security reasons.  Exposing that level of control remotely...

Comment: This is kind of an Admin tool. So the client is an admin application

Comment: Killing threads at random is rarely a good idea, since you have no idea about the internal state of the thread. Instead use whatever signaling mechanism you like to post an abort message to the thread and let the thread handle it properly.

Comment: But the thread i want to kill or suspend is waiting to be signalled. How can i post an message it? Is it possible

Comment: Let me put it another way: Instead of killing the waiting threads, you should investigate why they are waiting and if there's something wrong with the synchronization you should fix that.

Comment: Instead of waiting on a single event, add a terminate event and wait on them both.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly recommended that you find another method to signal the threads to gracefully conclude their loops but in answer to your question, yes it is possible.
Take a look at the System.Diagnostics.Process class.  From there you can examine the threads for a given process.  You can call Abort() on the threads you wish to terminate.